# How could type_traits know all of informations about polymorphism at compile time

Tags: c++11, polymorphism, runtime, type-traits, compile-time

I'm learning how to use `type_traits` with C++11 and I'm told that `type_traits` works at compile time.

I'm really surprised. I've made a test as below:

```
class A {virtual void foo();};
class B : public A {};

constexpr bool b = std::is_base_of<A, B>::value;
constexpr bool bb = std::is_polymorphic<A>::value;
constexpr bool bb2 = std::is_polymorphic<B>::value;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I compile this piece of code with the command: `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -g` and get a binary file `a.out`.

Then I execute the command `objdump -dj .rodata a.out` and get the output:

```
./a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64    

Disassembly of section .rodata:

0000000000000830 <_IO_stdin_used>:
 830:   01 00 02 00                                         ....

0000000000000834 <_ZStL19piecewise_construct>:
        ...

0000000000000835 <_ZL1b>:
 835:   01                                                  .

0000000000000836 <_ZL2bb>:
 836:   01                                                  .

0000000000000837 <_ZL3bb2>:
 837:   01                                                  .
```

OK, `type_traits` does work at compile time.

But how? Or does it mean that the c++ compiler could get all of polymorphism information at compile time? I always thought that polymorphism information was all about runtime stuff...

Comment: For the example shown with the `A` and `B` classes, there's no polymorphism involved. It all comes down to templates and template meta-programming techniques.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  Alright, I just made another example.

Comment: [This `std::is_polymorphic` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_polymorphic) shows [a possible implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_polymorphic#Possible_implementation). It's still handled by templates, and templates are compile-time constructs.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  So which kinds of informations are the runtime information, which can't be `type_traits`? You see I'm kind of confused about compile time and runtime on polymorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A polymorphic type is a type whose *instances* can exhibit polymorphic behaviour (virtual function calls, type erasure, RTTI, etc). The behaviour itself happens at runtime, but that possibility is already known at compile time — if only because the compiler has to generate the internal data structures that enable it (vtables, etc).

For example, given two mystery types `X` and `Y`:

```
void check(X const &x) {
    if(dynamic_cast<Y *>(&x))
        std::cout << "We have a Y!\n";
}
```

... the condition will pass at runtime iff `Y` is one of the dynamic types of `x`, but the function itself will only compile if the `dynamic_cast` is valid, that is if `X` and `Y` are polymorphic types.